# while loop in ssh going infinite in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

date1=$1
date2=$2

startday=${date1#*-*-}
startmonthday=${date1#*-}
startmonth=${startmonthday%%-*}
startyear=${date1%%-*-*}

endday=${date2#*-*-}
endmonthday=${date2#*-}
endmonth=${endmonthday%%-*}
endyear=${date2%%-*-*}


#set current and end date
current=$startyear$startmonth$startday
end=$endyear$endmonth$endday
end=$(date -d "$end + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d") ;
#loop over all dates
ssh -T user@server << EOF
cd path
pwd
        while [ $end != $current ] 
        do
        {
                echo $current;
                current=$(date -d "$current + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d") ;
        }
        done
exit
EOF
```

This is my code.When i run this code it goes into infinite loop as according to me the below doesn't work
current=$(date -d "$current + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d") ;

When i write the code without ssh it all works fine.
Please tell me why it is not working.

```
    while [ $end != $current ] 
                do
                {
                        echo $current;
                        current=$(date -d "$current + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d") ;
                }
                done
```

my actual need is

```
    ssh -T user@server << EOF
    cd path
    pwd
            while [ $end != $current ] 
            do
            {
                    scp user2@server2:path/upd_$current*var* .
                    current=$(date -d "$current + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d") ;
            }
            done
    exit
    EOF
```

Please tell me how can i do this in a effective way 
I want to copy the files named as the below pattern.
upd_date-var.stats.xls
everyday a new file is there i want to copy the files having all dates between the 2 dates passed as argument

Comment: Maybe the server you `ssh` into is running a different operating system than your local system. Have you checked the documentation for the `date` command on the server? (eg `man date` or `date --help` while ssh'd into the server).

Comment: Yes i have checked the documentation of date command there. This script is qorking very well at the server but when i run this script from the local it dont work.